# Kotlin null pointer exception when inlined but not when separated

Tags: android, kotlin, null

When collapsing code down into a single line, a null pointer exception starts getting thrown. But if separated into multiple variables, then it works just fine. Noticed the issue when upgrading to kotlin 1.5.0 on android api 31.

Code inline:

```
embeddedBasket?.basket?.items?.items?.asSequence()?.map { it.productItem }?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf() // throws null pointer exception
```

Code separated:

```
val productResponses = embeddedBasket?.basket?.items?.items // null
val asSequence = productResponses?.asSequence() // null
val map = asSequence?.map { it.productItem } // null
val toMutableList = map?.toMutableList() // null
val endList = toMutableList ?: mutableListOf() // Empty MutableList
```

Any idea why?

Edit:

Found the cause of the issue. It was Gson producing null values when converting from json elsewhere in the codebase. [Gson and Kotlin issue](https://proandroiddev.com/safe-parsing-kotlin-data-classes-with-gson-4d560fe3cdd2)

Comment: Need to see more of the code in context. Kotlin code itself never directly throws NPE unless you use `!!`, do something funky with order of property access in the constructor, or do an unsafe function call on a reference with ambiguous nullability acquired from a Java method.

Comment: Can you edit your question and attach trace log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the issue. It was Gson producing null values when converting from json elsewhere in the codebase. [Gson and Kotlin issue](https://proandroiddev.com/safe-parsing-kotlin-data-classes-with-gson-4d560fe3cdd2)